# In BOTW where are the locations of all of the zora stone monuments

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Where are the locations of all of the Zora stone monuments for the quest where you have to take pictures of the monuments and then show them to the Zora guy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to find the locations would be to look at a map as a cheatsheet. [This one from Super Soluce](https://video-game-guide-walkthrough.supersoluce.com/solution/guide-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-side-quests/lanayru-region/zora-stone-monuments) shows where they all are located. [image: map]

However from what I can tell the site just contains the map and doesn't really guide you to them all. I could have just been looking in the wrong spot there, but I found a guide from [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Zora_Stone_Monuments#Zora_Stone_Monument_Part_10) thats pretty in depth on where to get all the monuments. It contains a video showing exactly how to get to all of them.